# Does registering .uk domains require being a UK Citizen?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, country-specific

I'm a Canadian citizen and I'm looking to register a .uk domain for a future project of mines.

I know that anyone can register a .co.uk domain, but I'm talking about the recently released .uk top-level domain.

Can I just register it as a Canadian, or can only British Citizens register .uk domains like how only Canadian citizens can register .ca domains?

Comment: Have you tried to buy one and see if it works for you? can't see anything explicitly mentioned regarding non-uk registrants.

Comment: The only restriction that I'm aware of is that if the `.co.uk`, (or `.org.uk` etc.) version of the domain is already registered, then you will not be able to register the `.uk` version unless you are the registrant of the former. Current UK registrants have priority until 2019.

Answer (score 4):

No, you do not have to be a UK citizen. If you have a .co.uk domain, you will be given rights to the corresponding .uk domain name and no one can register it during that period. Once that period expires, it's open game.

You can find more information here. http://www.dotuklaunch.uk/im-new-customer-how-do-i-get-one

Answer (score 0):

There are the [following additional restrictions](http://www.nominet.org.uk/uk-domain-names/registering-uk-domain/choosing-domain-name/rules) on the purchase of `.uk` second level domains:

> ### 7 SLD registrations (NOTE RESERVATION RIGHTS APPLY TO CERTAIN HOLDERS OF THIRD LEVEL REGISTRATIONS UNTIL 10 JUNE 2019)
>
> In order to register a new Domain Name as a SLD within .uk, the following requirements apply:
>
> - Any person may register a SLD within .uk
> - Where a registrant address is not within the United Kingdom, a UK address for service must also be supplied
> - PO Box addresses (or equivalent services) are not permitted
> - The sale of third level registrations to unrelated third parties is not permitted

So while you don't have to be a UK citizen, you do need to have an address you can be reached at (not a PO Box) within the UK.